# SVGs not Rendering in Next JS

Tags: image, svg, next.js, localhost, http-status-code-404

I've been following this NextJS tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWAUAOqCHks
and he gave a download link in the description to download with all the assets required to build the Car Website. I went through the tutorial without too many issues but not a single SVG works, all it shows is a broken page icon.

The Image is correctly imported, i checked and changed the path multiple times, moved the SVGs in other folders or outside any, checked the spelling, yet nothing works.

I inspected the localhost:3000 page and all SVGs have the Error 404. I restarted the PC, restarted Visual Studio Code, checked whether the SVGs missed something, created a whole new project and yet SVGs do NOT work.

Here's some pictures, so you get what i mean:

[SVG Logo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQhj0.png)

[Code and SVG Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiS7Q.png)

[Not Rendered SVGs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqb2P.png)

[Inspect Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foHKm.png)

I'm getting desperate, i need an answer please.
Getting a reply might take months, but i'll be waiting for a reply.

Comment: Did you try to place them in the `/public` directory? The way you're loading the files (without an import) means it'll look for static files found in `/public` not on your project's assets.